# You are not connected to tor yet...(tails 2.10.0

Tags: tails

When I try to connect to tor the onion circuits window pops up but only displays a blue bar at the top saying "You are not connected to tor yet..." It gives no circuits and no status. I turned off mac spoofing, and i configured the time in the terminal. I am using a TP-link 300mbps wifi card and i can access the unsafe browser without issue.

Comment: Why are you setting the time using the terminal? Tails should set the time automatically on boot.

Answer (score -1):

It takes some time to integrate the node into Tor network, on first run it can be even 5-10 minutes sometimes, so basically it's OK. You can post your Tor log and we will be able to take a look deeper if you need it

Comment: "integrate the node into Tor network"? What does that even mean?

Comment: 100% bootstrap + directory update. If you'll measure the speed of circuit creation and other speed metrics - you'll see the speedup break, and tracing the things shows the "updated" status of the directory table